# Error Header File To Convert IplImage to Bitmap

Tags: c++, opencv, bitmap, iplimage

I'm a newbie in OpenCV, an currently following a totorial to display an image using Windows Form App (Visual C++ 2008). The tutorial instruct me to make a header file independently (its called cvToBitmap.h) before applying it on the stdafx.h of the header file in the project. The header file is functioned to convert an image in IplImage format into bitmap format. But, when i compiled the program, it occured 50 program error in the header program.

Below is the cvToBitmap.h source program

```
#ifndef _CVTOBITMAP_H_
#define _CVTOBITMAP_H_

static void FillBitmapInfo (BITMAPINFO* bmi, int 
    width, int height, int bpp, int origin)
{
    assert ((bmi&&width>=0)&&(height>=0)&&((bpp==8)
        ||(bpp==24)||(bpp==32)));
    BITMAPINFOHEADER* bmih=&(bmi->bmiHeader);
    memset(bmih,0,sizeof(*bmih));
    bmih->biSize=sizeof(BITMAPINFOHEADER);
    bmih->biWidth=width;
    bmih->biHeight=origin?abs(height):-abs(height);
    bmih->biPlanes=1;
    bmih->biBitCount=(unsigned short)bpp;
    bmih->biCompression=BI_RGB;
    if(bpp==8){
        RGBQUAD* palatte = bmi->bmiColors;
        for(int i=0;i<256;i++){
            palette[i].rgbBlue=palette[i].rgbGreen=palette[i].rgbRed=(BYTE)i;
            palette[i].rgbReserved=0;
        }
    }
}

System::Drawing::Bitmap^ IplImageToBitmap(IplImage* src){
    SIZE size = (0,0);
    int channels=0;
    void* dst_ptr=0;
    const int channels0=3;
    int origin=0;
    CvMat stub,dst,*image;
    bool changed_size=false;

    HDC hdc=CreateCompatibleDC(0);
    if(CV_IS_IMAGE_HDR(src))
        origin=src->origin;
    image=cvGetMat(src,&stub);
    uchar buffer(sizeof(BITMAPINFO*)buffer;
    size.cx=src->width;
    size.cy=src->height;
    channels=channels0;
    FillBitmapInfo(binfo,size.cx,size.cy,channels*8,1);
    HBITMAP hBitmap=reateDIBSection(hdc, binfo,DIB_RGB_COLORS, &dst_ptr,0,0);
    if (hBitmap==NULL)
        return nullptr;
    cvInitMatHeader(&dst, size.cy,size.cx,CV_8UC3, dst_ptr, (size.cx*channels+3)&-4);
    cvConvertImage(image, &ddst, origin=0 ? CV_CVTIMG:0);
    System::Drawing::Bitmap^ bmpImage=
        System::Drawing::Image::FromHbitmap(
        System::IntPtr(hBitmap));
    DeleteObject(hBitmap);
    DeleteDC(hdc);
    return bmpImage;
}
#endif
```

And Below is the error info

```
1>C:\opencv\build\include\cvToBitmap.h(6) : error C2065: 'BITMAPINFO' : undeclared identifier
1>C:\opencv\build\include\cvToBitmap.h(6) : error C2065: 'bmi' : undeclared identifier
1>C:\opencv\build\include\cvToBitmap.h(7) : error C2062: type 'int' unexpected
1>C:\opencv\build\include\cvToBitmap.h(8) : error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '{'
1>C:\opencv\build\include\cvToBitmap.h(8) : error C2447: '{' : missing function header (old-style formal list?)
1>C:\opencv\build\include\cvToBitmap.h(29) : error C2065: 'SIZE' : undeclared identifier
1>C:\opencv\build\include\cvToBitmap.h(29) : error C2146: syntax error : missing ';' before identifier 'size'
1>C:\opencv\build\include\cvToBitmap.h(29) : error C2065: 'size' : undeclared identifier
1>C:\opencv\build\include\cvToBitmap.h(37) : error C2065: 'HDC' : undeclared identifier
1>C:\opencv\build\include\cvToBitmap.h(37) : error C2146: syntax error : missing ';' before identifier 'hdc'
1>C:\opencv\build\include\cvToBitmap.h(37) : error C2065: 'hdc' : undeclared identifier
1>C:\opencv\build\include\cvToBitmap.h(37) : error C3861: 'CreateCompatibleDC': identifier not found
1>C:\opencv\build\include\cvToBitmap.h(41) : error C2065: 'BITMAPINFO' : undeclared identifier
1>C:\opencv\build\include\cvToBitmap.h(41) : error C2059: syntax error : ')'
1>C:\opencv\build\include\cvToBitmap.h(42) : error C2065: 'size' : undeclared identifier
1>C:\opencv\build\include\cvToBitmap.h(42) : error C2228: left of '.cx' must have class/struct/union
1>        type is ''unknown-type''
1>C:\opencv\build\include\cvToBitmap.h(43) : error C2065: 'size' : undeclared identifier
1>C:\opencv\build\include\cvToBitmap.h(43) : error C2228: left of '.cy' must have class/struct/union
1>        type is ''unknown-type''
1>C:\opencv\build\include\cvToBitmap.h(45) : error C2065: 'binfo' : undeclared identifier
1>C:\opencv\build\include\cvToBitmap.h(45) : error C2065: 'size' : undeclared identifier
1>C:\opencv\build\include\cvToBitmap.h(45) : error C2228: left of '.cx' must have class/struct/union
1>        type is ''unknown-type''
1>C:\opencv\build\include\cvToBitmap.h(45) : error C2065: 'size' : undeclared identifier
1>C:\opencv\build\include\cvToBitmap.h(45) : error C2228: left of '.cy' must have class/struct/union
1>        type is ''unknown-type''
1>C:\opencv\build\include\cvToBitmap.h(45) : error C3861: 'FillBitmapInfo': identifier not found
1>C:\opencv\build\include\cvToBitmap.h(46) : error C2065: 'HBITMAP' : undeclared identifier
1>C:\opencv\build\include\cvToBitmap.h(46) : error C2146: syntax error : missing ';' before identifier 'hBitmap'
1>C:\opencv\build\include\cvToBitmap.h(46) : error C2065: 'hBitmap' : undeclared identifier
1>C:\opencv\build\include\cvToBitmap.h(46) : error C2065: 'hdc' : undeclared identifier
1>C:\opencv\build\include\cvToBitmap.h(46) : error C2065: 'binfo' : undeclared identifier
1>C:\opencv\build\include\cvToBitmap.h(46) : error C2065: 'DIB_RGB_COLORS' : undeclared identifier
1>C:\opencv\build\include\cvToBitmap.h(46) : error C3861: 'reateDIBSection': identifier not found
1>C:\opencv\build\include\cvToBitmap.h(47) : error C2065: 'hBitmap' : undeclared identifier
1>C:\opencv\build\include\cvToBitmap.h(49) : error C2065: 'size' : undeclared identifier
1>C:\opencv\build\include\cvToBitmap.h(49) : error C2228: left of '.cy' must have class/struct/union
1>        type is ''unknown-type''
1>C:\opencv\build\include\cvToBitmap.h(49) : error C2065: 'size' : undeclared identifier
1>C:\opencv\build\include\cvToBitmap.h(49) : error C2228: left of '.cx' must have class/struct/union
1>        type is ''unknown-type''
1>C:\opencv\build\include\cvToBitmap.h(49) : error C2065: 'size' : undeclared identifier
1>C:\opencv\build\include\cvToBitmap.h(49) : error C2228: left of '.cx' must have class/struct/union
1>        type is ''unknown-type''
1>C:\opencv\build\include\cvToBitmap.h(50) : error C2065: 'ddst' : undeclared identifier
1>C:\opencv\build\include\cvToBitmap.h(50) : error C2065: 'CV_CVTIMG' : undeclared identifier
1>C:\opencv\build\include\cvToBitmap.h(51) : error C2065: 'bmpImage' : undeclared identifier
1>C:\opencv\build\include\cvToBitmap.h(51) : error C2275: 'System::Drawing::Bitmap' : illegal use of this type as an expression
1>C:\opencv\build\include\cvToBitmap.h(53) : error C2065: 'hBitmap' : undeclared identifier
1>C:\opencv\build\include\cvToBitmap.h(54) : error C2065: 'hBitmap' : undeclared identifier
1>C:\opencv\build\include\cvToBitmap.h(54) : error C3861: 'DeleteObject': identifier not found
1>C:\opencv\build\include\cvToBitmap.h(55) : error C2065: 'hdc' : undeclared identifier
1>C:\opencv\build\include\cvToBitmap.h(55) : error C3861: 'DeleteDC': identifier not found
1>C:\opencv\build\include\cvToBitmap.h(56) : error C2065: 'bmpImage' : undeclared identifier
1>C:\opencv\build\include\cvToBitmap.h(57) : error C2143: syntax error : missing ')' before '}'
1>C:\opencv\build\include\cvToBitmap.h(57) : error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before ')'
    1>TampilForm - 50 error(s), 0 warning(s)
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

I have no idea, what is the missing part.. Please help.. thanks..

Comment: You need to include `windows.h`

Answer (score 0):

You should include header with `BITMAPINFO` structure - add `#include <windows.h>` to your header file.